# Stata: Calculate sum of any x in y?

Tags: stata

I have two variables:

1. One called packageid (the unique ID number for a company's loan)
2. The other is called ConventType, which has values of 1 to 21 each representing a type of covenant (loan).

I want to make a new variable (cov_sum) that is the sum of any covenanttype in packageid.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input double packageid long CovenantType
 4106 13
 4106 18
 4812 13
 4952  2
 5223  9
 5287 18
 7011  4
 7011 13
 7011 18
 7849 17
10261 17
11057  4
11178  4
11178 13
11178 18
11452 17
11714  4
11714 13
11954  2
11954 13
11954 18
12807 13
12807 18
end
```

So for example, packageid 4106 would have cov_sum = 2 because it has two CovenantType values, 13 and 18.

I've created 21 temporary variables to be 1 or 0 for each type of covenant, but I'm not sure how to do this last step to sum them for each packageid.

I'm aware it would create repetitive values, like below but that is okay.

```
input double packageid long CovenantType long? cov_sum
 4106 13 2
 4106 18 2
```

How can I create a variable that is the sum of any covenanttype in packageid?

Comment: When you say sum, you're really just counting, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
bysort packageid: generate n = _n
bysort packageid: egen cov_sum = max(n)

list, abbreviate(15)

     +----------------------------------------+
     | packageid   CovenantType   n   cov_sum |
     |----------------------------------------|
  1. |      4106             13   1         2 |
  2. |      4106             18   2         2 |
  3. |      4812             13   1         1 |
  4. |      4952              2   1         1 |
  5. |      5223              9   1         1 |
     |----------------------------------------|
  6. |      5287             18   1         1 |
  7. |      7011              4   1         3 |
  8. |      7011             13   2         3 |
  9. |      7011             18   3         3 |
 10. |      7849             17   1         1 |
     |----------------------------------------|
 11. |     10261             17   1         1 |
 12. |     11057              4   1         1 |
 13. |     11178              4   1         3 |
 14. |     11178             13   2         3 |
 15. |     11178             18   3         3 |
     |----------------------------------------|
 16. |     11452             17   1         1 |
 17. |     11714              4   1         2 |
 18. |     11714             13   2         2 |
 19. |     11954              2   1         3 |
 20. |     11954             13   2         3 |
     |----------------------------------------|
 21. |     11954             18   3         3 |
 22. |     12807             13   1         2 |
 23. |     12807             18   2         2 |
     +----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: `bysort packageid : gen cov_sum = _N` would seem to be more direct. (You know this really....)